# Magic Missile vs Rug of Smothering

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, monsters

If you cast Magic Missile on a Rug of Smothering, does it still deal half damage to the grappled creature? I know that by RAW it should, but it makes no sense, because Magic Missiles can’t miss. Is there an errata or anything for this?

Comment: How does it not make sense? What does Magic Missile not being able to miss have to do with anything?

Comment: @PurpleMonkey If you can hit a fly with your Missile you should be able to have enough control not to kill your friend by accident.

Comment: The same could be said about *any* attack that hits. If you actually read the rug's ability though, accuracy of the attack doesn't mean anything.

Comment: @PurpleMonkey I guess you are right

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Yes, damage is split between the *Rug* and its victim.

This has nothing to do with hitting or missing the [*Rug of Smothering*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/rug-of-smothering). Per the *Rug*s description:

> *Damage Transfer.* While it is grappling a creature, the rug takes only
> half the damage dealt to it, and the creature grappled by the rug
> takes the other half.

Some creatures regenerate, some have Darkvision, the *Rug of Smothering* just happens to have an ability that transfers damage it takes to its victim. This also makes narrative sense when you consider that the person grappled is wrapped up in the rug, kinda like a PC burrito. Stab the rug, your blade is bound to find its way into the person in the middle. The same would go for *Magic Missile*.